# How to clear parameters from a Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase object?

Tags: enterprise-library

I know you can add parameters , but how do you clear the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ClearParameterCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.clearparametercache(BTS.10).aspx) method should do it.